# In R, how can I check whether a list contains a particular key?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a list as follows

```
foo=list(bar="hello world")
```

I would like to check whether my list has a particular key.
I observe `foo$bar2` will return `NULL` for any `bar2` that is not equal to `bar`, so I figured I could check for whether the return value was null, but this does not seem to work:

```
if (foo$bar2==NULL) 1 # do something here
```

However, this gives the error:

```
Error in if (foo$bar2 == NULL) 1 : argument is of length zero
```

I then tried whether NULL is equivalent to false, like in C:

```
if (foo$bar2) 1 # do something here
```

This gives the same error.

I now have two questions. How can I check whether the list contains the key?
And how do I check whether an expression is null?

Comment: Use `is.null(...)` to see if something is null

Comment: What do you mean check if you list contains the key? What's the "key" in this situation?

Comment: The key is the name of the element in the list. The valid key here would be `bar`. I'm not sure if the `R` community has a different word for it, but the `R` list looks like a Python dictionary to me, which is why I referred to the name as a "key".

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The notion of "keys" are called "names" in R.

```
if ("bar" %in% names(foo) ) {  print("it's there") }  # ....
```

They are stored in a special attribute named `.Names` and extracted with the `names` function:

```
dput(foo)
#structure(list(bar = "hello world"), .Names = "bar")
```

I offer a semantic caution here, because of a common source of confusion due to two distinct uses of the word: "names" in R: There are `.Names`-attributes, but there is an entirely different use of the word `name` in R that has to do with strings or tokens that have values independent of any inspection or extraction functions like `$` or `[`. Any token that starts with a letter or a period and has no other special characters in it can be a valid `name`. One can test for it with the the function `exists` given a quoted version of its `name`:

```
 exists("foo")  # TRUE
#assume ‘foo’ is a list with a named element “bar”
exists(”bar”)  #  [1] FALSE (even though it’s a “name”
 exists(foo$bar) #    [1] FALSE
 exists("foo$bar")#    [1] FALSE
```

So the word `name` has two different meanings in R and you will need to be aware of this ambiguity to understand how the language is deployed. The `.Names` meaning refers to an attribute with special purposes, while the `names`-meaning refers to what is called a "language-object". The word `symbol` is a synonym for this second meaning of the word.

```
is.name( quote(foo) ) #[1] TRUE
```

To then show how your second question about testing for nullity might flow into this :

```
if( !is.null(foo$bar) ) {  print("it's there") }  # any TRUE value will be a 1
```